# How is lucene boosting affected by lengthNorm similarity

Tags: java, lucene, similarity, solr-boost

I have two docs containing:

**doc_1**: `one two three four five Bingo`

**doc_2**: `Bingo one two three four five`

Which I am indexing in two fields each, where one field contains the first 5 terms, and the second contains the last term.

```
TextField start_field = new TextField("start_words", content.substring(0, index), Field.Store.NO);
TextField end_field = new TextField("end_words", content.substring(index,content.length()-1, Field.Store.NO);
// index is index value of 5th ' '
```

In order to see boosting results better, I have implemented the following similarity:

```
DefaultSimilarity customSimilarity = new DefaultSimilarity() {
     @Override
     public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState state) {
         return 1; // So length of each field would not matter
     }
};
```

Without applying any boost, searching for `Bingo` results in both documents having the same score (as expected and intended).
However, when applying a boost to one of the fields (`start_field.setBoost(5)`), both scores remain identical, although **doc_2**'s field containing `Bingo` was boosted.

If I remove the `customSimilarity`, boosting works as expected.

Why is `boosting` stopped by `lengthNorm` and how can I make the boosting work with the given overwritten Similarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [default implementation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/DefaultSimilarity.html#lengthNorm(org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState)) of `lengthNorm()` in `DefaultSimilarity` is `state.getBoost() * lengthNorm(numTerms)`.

In your implementation, you are not factoring in the boost. To make your boosts matter, you could just have your implementation return `state.getBoost()`.